# Relative path in absolute URI in MS Databricks Spark when reading csv file

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks

I am new to Pyspark and am trying to use the database from Databricks.

I was trying to read a csv file from my local computer using this syntax:

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", True).load("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\MasterFile_v0.csv")
```

and got this error message: `java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: C:%5CUsers%5C****.10%5CDesktop%5CMasterFile_v0.csv`

Just wonder how to fix this.

Also, I used Pandas to read csv but need to install xlrd, and I used `%pip install xlrd` inside databricks but seems that I don't have the credential to do so.

If there is any suggestions for me to read local files, that would great. Thanks!
C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the file on your computer from the Databricks - it runs in the cloud, and no way the cluster may have access to your local disk.

You need to upload file to Databricks file system. There are multiple ways to do that (listed in [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data.html)):

1. using [Upload Data UI](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#user-interface)
2. Using [Databricks CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/dbfs-cli.html) (may not work with community edition)
3. Put file onto cloud storage (Azure data lake, AWS S3, etc.), and access it from Spark